# Bootstrap v3.3.1 Column Becoming too Wide

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using col-xs-1 column makes it look good on small displays, but it becomes too wide on large displays. I understand I can limit it with max-width but then there's a lot of blank, unused space. Is there a way to limit column width and stretch other columns to available space since screen is divided to "only" 12 parts?

Comment: You could customize Bootstraps grid system to use more than 12 columns, look for the `@grid-columns` variable in http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Add also other classes .col-lg and .col-md then it will remain in limit.